# JavaScript error on Firefox: TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property "userAgent"

Tags: javascript, firefox, navigator

I'm currently receiving a weird JavaScript error on my error monitoring tool Sentry that says `can't redefine non-configurable property "userAgent"`.

It seems like the error is happening on multiple pages but only on Firefox. Additionally, on all errors the referrer page seems to be "https://www.startpage.com/".

However, I'm not able to reproduce the error and have no clue whats causing the error as I do not have any assignments to the `navigator.userAgent` var.

Does anyone else have this issue, too, or has any clue what could cause this error?

Comment: This one is pretty cryptic. I have it on my app too and its taken me a while to figure out what is going on. Do you happen to be doing any browser detection ? even if you dont have assignments to the navigator.userAgent, are you trying to sniff the browser with it?

Comment: Yes, I actually do have a check on the user agent like this `navigator.userAgent === 'native'`. I`m setting the user agent within my native app's webview to 'native' to be able to detect whether my website is visited within a normal browser or within a webview of my app. But the errors do not occur while using my native app, just via the Firefox browser. Do you think the check could still cause the issue?

Comment: It could be possible that a firefox extension/setting is messing with the user Agent. This article is very useful to explain that we should not be using the userAgent to determine browsers, even mobile. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent     


So for me, my guess is that the user has a setting or an extension in firefox that allows them to overwrite their userAgent and perhaps this gets logged into the console because we are using userAgent to derive browser info.

Comment: @EstherCuan Very interesting! Thank you for the information! :)

Comment: Hope it helps get you closer to the source :)

Comment: I got reports of this error in Sentry two time the past months. Firefox 86 and 85, but no clue what the cause is. Very little information provided in the Sentry event. No tickets have been created for this event. I don't use `userAgent` in the application code, it's used by dependencies so my first step will be to upgrade them. And I'll try to get more information in Sentry. And then we wait 

Comment: You should say more about this: "I`m setting the user agent within my native app's webview to 'native'"   If you're running a single codebase in both native and browser environments, you absolutely need to be prepared for the fact that some statements that work in one context will not work in others. I'd want more details on this.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you are setting your navigator.userAgent and it becomes read-only. You could do in this way: `Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'userAgent', {value: 'my-value', configurable: true, writable: true}))`

Comment: I get them too. Not even testing user agent. The error is reported as happening at character 130 on line one of the page, which is right between 2 meta tags... There's no a single element of inline javascript anywhere in the page, so my guess is, it's coming from some extension injecting inline JS in the DOM, and failing. Best to ignore them, or filter them out.

Comment: Recently I have been getting a large number of errors of this type. Like Capsule, the error is reported at character 130 of line 1. My previous investigation points to a Firefox extension being the cause, but there is no hard evidence. Would sure be nice to understand this better.

Comment: Has anyone who can reproduce this tried testing each extension? You can do this by ensuring all extensions are not allowed to run in incognito mode then opening an incognito window and loading an affected page. Next, re-enable each extension for incognito mode and test to see if the error is triggered. Eventually you'll find the extension causing this or find that the cause is not an extension.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this exact message before when trying to call `Object.defineProperty` on a property that is 'non-configureable' in strict mode.  You have something in your code or in one of your deps that is trying to redefine a property using this method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_delete