# Error can't redefine non-configurable property "userAgent"

Tags: javascript, user-agent

Lately we have been getting a lot of javascript errors "can't redefine non-configurable property "userAgent"".

We don't attempt to redefine userAgent in our code. We barely even reference userAgent. The only places would be in code like the following:

```
var browser_msie = (navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/trident/i)) ? true : false;
```

I am wondering if this error is rather coming from some bad browser behavior. It only started showing up recently.

Last evening we got over 20,000 of such error messages, and all from the same member of our service.

EDIT

The error information is as follows:

Error Message:

```
Message: TypeError: can&amp;#39;t redefine non-configurable property &amp;#34;userAgent&amp;#34;
URL: https://www.rephunter.net/member-home.php
Line:1
Column:130
Stack:@https://www.rephunter.net/member-home.php:1:130


Error Traceback: 

#0 Called backtrace in file /var/www/rephunter/www/webroot/include/error-handler-inc.php as line #68
#1 Called error_handler in file  as line #
#2 Called trigger_error in file /var/www/rephunter/www/webroot/ajax/javascript-error.php as line #14
```

Unfortunately this offers no help, as line 1 of the page is just `<!DOCTYPE html>`. I don't see how to get to that part of the code. Of course if that were possible it might be easy to see the cause of the issue.

I recall in the past the Dev Tools might have given a "spiders view" of the page, but now I only see the DOM on the Elements tab, and Sources. Both of these are formatted and their is no way to see what "line 1 char 130" means.

Comment: There should be a line number in the error message, that should tell you where it's happening.

Comment: Is it an error or a warning?

Comment: It might be coming from a library you're using. Or if you show ads, it could be coming from their code, not yours.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66033349/javascript-error-on-firefox-typeerror-cant-redefine-non-configurable-property (also without answer)